# onAuthenticationSuccess giving me events as parameters

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following handler on authentication success:

```
app_auth_success_handler:
        class: App\UserBundle\Security\User\Handler\LoginAuthSuccessHandler
        public: true
        arguments: ['@router', "@service_container"]
        tags:
             - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.success, method: onAuthenticationSuccess }
```

```
class LoginAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $container;

    /**
    * Constructor
    * @param RouterInterface   $router
    */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, $container)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
```

However after I authenticate the user it gives me this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to App\UserBundle\Security\User\Handler\LoginAuthSuccessHandler::onAuthenticationSuccess() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent given in /Users/John/Sites/App/src/Shopious/UserBundle/Security/User/Handler/LoginAuthSuccessHandler.php on line <i>31</i></th></tr>
```

Can't figure out why this is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaking the `security.authentication.success` event with the `success_handler` which you can define in your firewall config.

The service for a `success_handler` can be any service implementing `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface`.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class LoginAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {}
}
```

It doesn't need to tagged as an event listener:

```
app_auth_success_handler:
    class: App\UserBundle\Security\User\Handler\LoginAuthSuccessHandler
    public: true
    arguments: ['@router', "@service_container"]
```

Instead the service name is passed to the firewall config:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                success_handler: app_auth_success_handler
```